# php jquery mysql - load more button in another loadmore in loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have two files for a load more button for posts but I can't use another load more for posts  replay
this is one load more code:
file index.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var comco = 2;
  var offset = 0;
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "ld_comco.php",
        data: { comnco: comco, offset: offset }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        $("#comnts").append(msg);
      });
    offset = offset + comco;
  });

  $("#btn1").trigger("click");
});
</script>
<div  id="comnts"></div>
<button id="btn1">load more</button>
```

and this is the ld_comco.php file:

```
$comnco=$_POST['comnco'];
$offset=$_POST['offset'];

$qq="SELECT * FROM tbl_users_posts limit $offset, $comnco";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
    echo $fff['post'];}
```

I do change the `ld_comco.php` file for add repost button inside the posts:

```
$comnco=$_POST['comnco'];
$offset=$_POST['offset'];

$qq="SELECT * FROM tbl_users_posts limit $offset, $comnco";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   $sbid=$fff['id'];
    echo $fff['post'];
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var recomco = 2;
  var sbid = <?php echo $sbid?>;
  var reoffset = 0;
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "ld_recomco.php",
        data: { recomnco: recomco, reoffset: reoffset }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        $("#recomnts").append(msg);
      });
    reoffset = reoffset + recomco;
  });

  $("#btn2").trigger("click");
});
</script>
<?php }?>
<div  id="recomnts"></div>
<button id="btn2">load more re-pst</button>
```

and add a `ld_recomco.php` file:

```
$recomnco=$_POST['recomnco'];
$reoffset=$_POST['reoffset'];
$sbid=$_POST['sbid'];

$qq2="SELECT * FROM re_pst WHERE subid=$sbid limit $reoffset, $recomnco";
$qr2=mysqli_query($conn,$qq2);while($fff2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr2)){
    echo $fff2['id'];
    echo $fff2['remsg'];
}
```

This dosen't work properly, how can I do this?

---

Edit:
i have the user posts in a while-loop like this:

```
$qq="SELECT * FROM tbl_users_posts";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   $sbid=$fff['id'];
    echo $fff['post'];}
```

i can add -load more- button to post but i cant add -load more- button to posts replay
in some code like this:

```
$qq="SELECT * FROM tbl_users_posts limit 10";
$qr=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);while($fff=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
   $sbid=$fff['id'];
    echo $fff['post'];?>
<?php   $qq2="SELECT * FROM re_pst WHERE subid=$sbid";
    $qr2=mysqli_query($conn,$qq2);while($fff2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr2)){
        echo $fff2['remsg'];
    }}
```

Comment: A hint outside your question: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
If I would manually post ";TRUNCATE TABLE re_pst" as value for your query to your code I would be able to clear your entire table..
You should escape your input variables.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean:  ";TRUNCATE TABLE re_pst" as value

Comment: Your problem is unclear.

Comment: i add some more codes for more clarification.